# Automatic replacing of [ with []

Tags: front-end, keyboard

I tried to modify the `KeyEventTranslations.tr` file in order to always place a closed bracket instead of an open bracket once I press `[`. However once I press `[` after the modification nothing happens (the cursor just stays at the same position and not even a `[` is placed).

```
Item[KeyEvent["["],
        FrontEndExecute[{
            FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
                "[", After],
            FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
                "]", Before]
        }]],
```

the Code is a slight modification of what i found regarding double brackets:

[Automating Esc [[ Esc formatting?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/automating-esc-esc-formatting)

(There is a comment below the top answer, which also mentions Problems regarding `[` and German keyboard language).

If I use a different character like `/` to trigger the `KeyEvent`, which does not have to be typed using the AltGr-key

```
Item[KeyEvent["/"],
        FrontEndExecute[{
            FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
                "[", After],
            FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
                "]", Before]
        }]],
```

the closed bracket will be placed as expected. Other keys like `{` using `AltGr` do not work either.

I tried renaming the `term.dll` files as suggested here:

[Is it possible to get AltGr key to work in Math.exe?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45928/is-it-possible-to-get-altgr-key-to-work-in-math-exe)

unfortunately this did not fix the Problem.

Additional Information: I'm using Win7 and my keyboard language is set to German. (And I would like to keep it set to German).

If there is any other way circumventing the `KeyEventTranslations.tr` to automaticaly place `[]` with the cursor placed between the brackets once I press `[`, it would be fine as well.

Thanks in advance if anyone tries to answer my question :)

Comment: Are aware of the fact that Alt-] inserts a matching `[ ]` pair? No modifications necessary.

Comment: With keyboard language set to german that does not work for me. Pressing `AltGr-Alt-8` (`AltGr-]`) does not yield any front end input for me. As a side note: Pressing `Ctrl-Alt` is equivalent to pressing `AltGr` on my keyboard.

Comment: With exception to basic editing and saving commands (`Ctrl-A`, `Ctrl-S` etc.) keyboard shortcuts do not work when keyboard locale is not set to English. Also the FrontEnd generally cannot handle correctly characters outside of Unicode level 0.

Comment: How about using `FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["InsertMatchingBrackets"]]` instead of the two `FrontEndExecute`s you used?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I just tried, but it did not work. The problem is probably the `KeyEvent["["]`. In case there exists no proper solution I will just map `[]` to `)`, since I mapped `()` to `(` I dont really need the `)` key anymore.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Most of the shortcuts normaly work for me (even more complex ones involving 2 modifiers). So I guess that means I can not expect every shortcut to work because german localization is not fully supported.