# AltGr randomly stops working - Windows 7

Tags: keyboard

My problem is that AltGr just randomly and frequently stops working. I've only seen this problem since the last update (10.1). The only sure way to recover functionality that I've found was to change the keyboard setup (alt+shift). I'm using multiple keyboards on my system so I need to rotate between the languages back to the one I use in Mathematica every time this happens.

I saw [Is it possible to get AltGr key to work in Math.exe?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45928/is-it-possible-to-get-altgr-key-to-work-in-math-exe)
but it seems to be on another issue.

I'm running Windows 7.

Considering how I can recover the functionality, I suppose that it might be a Windows issue, but I've not noticed this behavior anywhere else.

EDIT:
I just noticed that when AltGr looses it's 'normal' functionality, it activates the menu bar instead.

Comment: Such shortcuts as Alt + "/" etc. work only in English locale. Probably that's the reason for the behavior you observe.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean that your keyboard input language should be English in order to have the keyboard shortcuts like `Alt+/`, `Alt+]` etc. working.

Comment: It's not a problem of my keyboard input language. In the language I'm using, for example brackets are mapped to the AltGr+Number-keys and it's these combinations that stop working (without me changing language input) since AltGr for some reason starts activating the menu bar in the Mathematica input window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Altough I haven't seen this behavior in other programs, it does indeed seem to be a Windows issue that can occur when you're using multiple keyboard layouts (where AltGr has different functions on different layouts, e.g. as a menu activation key in American layout vs activating a third character on other keys).

Some services when activated in Windows causes this conflict to happen and in my case it was the Remote Desktop Service. There doesn't seem to exist a known solution to this problem, but a workaround is to identify the conflicting service and disabling it, if you don't need the service.

Comment: Had a similar issue with e.g.  consoles on virtual servers,  which hijacked the key mappings...